# Importing fecha doesn't work in combination with Jest in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs, typescript-typings

I would like to use [fecha 3.0.2](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) for formatting dates in my TypeScript project. However, only my little test case doesn't work.

```js
import fecha from "fecha";
console.log(fecha.format(new Date(), "YYYY"));
```

This snippets seems to be correct for Visual Studio Code. However, when I try to compile it via webpack, I get an error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined).

The TypeScript definitions [fecha.d.ts](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha/blob/master/src/fecha.d.ts) for [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha/blob/master/src/fecha.js) look good for me.

I'm using webpack 4.28.3 and TypeScript 3.2.2.

In `fecha.js`, `fetch` is exported like this:

```js
export default fecha;
```

...where that `fecha` variable is declared and initialized like this:

```js
var fecha = {};
```

...and methods like `format` are added like this:

```js
fecha.format = function (// ...
```

---

**EDIT:** I have created a minimal example project for reproducing the error

src/app.ts

```js
import fecha from "fecha";
console.log(fecha.format(new Date(), "YYYY"));
```

src/app.test.ts

```js
import fecha from "fecha";

it("format date", () => {
    expect(fecha.format(new Date(), "YYYY")).toEqual("2019");
});
```

package.json

```js
{
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "fecha": "3.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "23.3.12",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
        "jest": "23.6.0",
        "ts-jest": "23.10.5",
        "typescript": "3.2.2",
        "webpack": "4.28.3",
        "webpack-cli": "3.2.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "transform": { ".ts": "ts-jest" },
        "testRegex": "\\.test\\.ts$",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [ "js", "ts" ]
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
    "include": [ "./src/" ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: { loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' } }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

`yarn webpack -p` works, but `yarn jest` throws a TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined. So, it seems jest and fecha doesn't like each other. Is there a way to use fecha for my jest tests?

Comment: That's definitely the right way to import it given the export it provides. It sounds like the import isn't being resolved correctly (though why that wouldn't be a "can't find module" or similar is unclear to me)...

Comment: Could you be trying to import `fecha.d.ts` rather than `fecha.js`? I ask because `fecha.d.ts` ends with `declare const fechaObj: Fecha;` `export default fechaObj;` [In the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20const%20foo%3A%20Date%3B%0Aexport%20default%20foo%3B), doing that results in a default export with the value `undefined` -- exactly what you're seeing in your error.

Comment: If I import `fecha.d.ts` directly, I will get a refererence error (ReferenceError: fechaObj is not defined). I don't think that a definition file can work standalone.

Comment: No, it clearly can't. I'm just saying, that would fit the symptom (somewhat, but actually, no, since as you say, in that playground example `foo` is never declared, so it would throw a ReferencError -- and thus the same for fechaObj).

Comment: The problem is clearly Webpack-related. If I download `fecha.js` and use exactly the import you provide (well, `import fecha from "./fecha.js";` because I'm using native browser module support, not Webpack), it works just fine.

Comment: I'm going to create a minimal example project. I hope this will help to isolate the cause for this strange error.

Comment: I have added the example project. It seems that the combination of jest and fecha is the cause for the type error. However, I don't understand why and how to solve it.